# Update Facebook Page Tab with PHP GraphApi

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to update a Facebook Page Tab details (custom_name, custom_image_url) via GraphAPI? In earlier API versions it was possible to update a tab by issuing POST request to this endpoint:

[PAGE_ID]/tabs/app_[APP_ID]

But now, I get an exception (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: v2.2110615188986707...

**Update**:
I just figured out that it works, but I'm currently having problems with custom_image_url [as I have a local development url that is not accessible by facebook ;)] so I'll try to upload a file instead of giving the url to it...

Answer (score 0):

Updating

You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs/

ps: no more update in latest fb api, i also can update page tab custom name, etc previous, by recently fb api had remove this api, so we can't do anything about it.